# Cannot post answers: Unable to reach Recaptcha service

Tags: bug

I have been unable to post answers on Stack Overflow for a while: the Human Verification popup comes up, I click the check box, answer the recaptcha question, the check mark appears, and after about 15 seconds, an error message "Unable to reach Recaptcha service" appears in red and the post fails.

Is this a known problem?

Is is related to something on my side?

I have tested with and without a proxy, with the same outcome.  It is quite frustrating to be unable to post answers.  Why does the Human Verification popup appear even when I am connected?  Why is the connection not done via https to avoid spoofing robots?

Comment: Maybe try clearing your cache, or try a different browser. Can you post questions ? People in chat are saying that Stack Exchange is having some problems, (Login, Snippets not working,) So maybe just wait a while.

Comment: There are network problems at the moment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus this might be related

Comment: The question has been tagged as *off topic* because the circumstances cannot be reproduced.  Should I delete my answer and the question?

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to have disappeared.  It may have been a side effect of the ISP change that was underway.

Comment: When I work under some vpn exposing same Ip for large requests with different credentials from different users it happens. Even Google search requires captcha many a times..