# To include proper information for reproducing any bug on Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, meta, stack-exchange

People face different UI issues and bugs on different platforms to target them and fix them, we discuss it here on meta so it can be later fixed.

### The actual problem is

Users do not include enough information to reproduce these bugs so they can be seen and judged by people for fixing it. Instead, they explain about the issue or bug in text or include a screenshot which renders it useless to see it and fix it.

### What actual problem this assessment solves

To create a standard template for reporting bugs. It is drafted in my answer below.

A reason why I posted my question because users do not include enough information for reproducing it. These questions were closed because they didn't include enough information to reproduce them and most of them need fixing

- [Removing tags on mobile makes screen jump](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385187/removing-tags-on-mobile-makes-screen-jump)
- [Stack Overflow reloading automatically every 30 seconds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332517/stack-overflow-reloading-automatically-every-30-seconds)
- [Line under featured tab missing in Chrome](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366277/line-under-featured-tab-missing-in-chrome)
- [Cannot post answers: Unable to reach Recaptcha service](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294513/cannot-post-answers-unable-to-reach-recaptcha-service)
- [Breakage when editing code segment in comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320367/breakage-when-editing-code-segment-in-comment)
- [Why does this Windows batch code cause an error when posting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285533/why-does-this-windows-batch-code-cause-an-error-when-posting)
- ["Internation roaming" needs to be fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367431/internation-roaming-needs-to-be-fixed)

Comment: What is the feature you are requesting?

Comment: A feature for bug reports @HereticMonkey

Comment: As it notes in the [tag info for `feature-request`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info): "Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature." It's not clear to me how this "bug report template" would be implemented, considering we also (desperately) want questions which are not bug reports on the site. Also, the question wizard prompts for some of this already...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am talking about bug reports for StackOverflow which are posted on meta. Question wizard is a StackOverflow feature, right?

Comment: Sorry, where in your question does it mention Meta Stack Overflow? (BTW, the sites' names are two words: "Stack Overflow" and "Stack Exchange").

Comment: @HereticMonkey _we discuss it here on meta so it can be later fixed._

Comment: Kinda "burying the lede" there. I suggest you add it to the title ("...any bug on Meta Stack Overflow"), and that you capitalize it and combine with the site name, so there's no room for confusion. You also need to be clear how this template would be enforced: The points you make *should* be clear to anyone who's ever programmed some code and had to maintain it, but, well, people are lazy.

Comment: @HereticMonkey agreed and edited the question, I think that if people started using this template to post bugs, then anyone can reproduce the issue and better fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For browser related issues

The user should include this information in their question

1. Actual Issue in text

   - For the user to explain the issue first in text, so we can understand it from the core.
2. Steps to reproduce the issue

   - Provided steps by the OP to reproduce the issue from scratch in points and sequence.
3. Platform name and Operating system information

   - This includes your source of using stack overflow and the operating system you are using.
4. Browser version

   - This is very important as bugs vary on different browsers
5. The URL of the page which is the bug on

   - For people on StackExchange to track down the bug and solve it
6. Optional information about what the console says

   - Helpful optional information about the error.

### For mobile devices issues

The user should include this information in their question

1. Actual Issue in text
2. Steps to reproduce the issue from the start of the MainActivity or the first page.
3. Android/iOS version and Stackoverflow's application version, as seen from the store.
4. Reference to the page, the issue is actually on
5. A screenshot of the issue

   - I really feel sorry for people in Turkey and other countries, [who cannot access Imgur](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385165/can-stack-overflow-use-a-different-domain-for-images-instead-of-stack-imgur-com). For them, this point is an exception and instead, they should include extra information that includes

     1. Extra reference for the behavior of the issue and the page on it, they have to explain what the page is in text, they can also use proxies but as they limit features, they can use this approach
     2. List the optimal points that describe the issue, what it is not allowing you to do? What UI component is not working as it should?
6. Optional crash information, the application gives

This template is not perfect and can be edited later, but what's most essential that if we follow the template, we can better target bugs and fix it. Bug reports should be in a format so they can be reproduced. People at StackExchange can better see the issue's platform and information and make this site better and better. 
 Most importantly,
**Users who are willing to help now not need to wait and ask for the browser version, platform, and steps to reproduce the issue.**